# Cypress how to select option containing text

Tags: cypress

In Cypress, the `select('option-text')` command will only work if there is an exact match. How can I tell it to select an option that *contains* the text instead ?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to select an option that just contains the text? Tell us more about your scenario. Thanks for the answer below

Comment: Sure. I have a `<select>` with options that contain not only the name of the thing, but also some optional details. To give a random example, it could be the name of a product, associated to its price (to help with the choice). In the context of the test I was writing, the only thing I could easily grab programmatically was the name, not the price. Let's also mention that I can rely on the bijection that exists between names and options (no need for the price to select a specific option).

Comment: BTW if that's what brought you here, I've accepted my own answer, sorry for having forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything like that in the api so far, nor in the github issues.

So I resorted to adding a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) in my project:

```js
// cypress/support/commands.ts
Cypress.Commands.add('selectContaining', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject, text, options) => {
  return cy.wrap(subject).contains('option', text, options).then(
    option => cy.get('select#report-selection').select(option.text().trim())
  );
});
```

```js
// cypress/support/commands_type.ts
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    requestApi(method: HttpMethod, url: string, body?: RequestBody): Chainable<Cypress.Response>;
    selectContaining(text: string | string[], options?: Partial<SelectOptions>): Chainable<Subject>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Through aliasing you can make it work:

```js
cy.get('select')
  .find('option')
  .contains('YOUR TEXT')
  .as('selectOption')
  .then( () => {
    cy.get('select')
      .select(`${this.selectOption.text()}`)
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

A slightly improved variant of Can Akgun user is as following (bonus adding as cypress command):

```js
 /**
 * Select an option containing part of string in its text body
 * {String} elementSelector
 * {String} optionTextPart
 */
 Cypress.Commands.add('selectOptionContaining', (elementSelector, optionTextPart) => {
    cy.get(elementSelector)
    .find('option')
    .contains(optionTextPart)
    .then($option => {
        cy.get(elementSelector).select($option.text());
    });
});
```

In this way we do not need global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I use this format to choose by text.

```
cy.get('select').find('option').contains('YOUR TEXT').then((selectOption) => {  
            cy.get('select').select(selectOption.text());
});
```